# Как в python kivy открыть окно поверх окна

Tags: python, kivy, label

Возник вопрос, как поверх основной разметки в python kivy по нажатию кнопки открывать Label?

Comment: FloatLayout умеет накладывать элементы

Comment: Можно сделать Popup и в нем создать Label